# Using ngx-mqtt in angular project not giving old data(behaves like hot observable)

Tags: angular, mqtt

I have used ngx-mqtt in angular project. There is another project which created data, and send data to particular topic.When i m subscribing to this topic from angular application, i always get data from time of subscription whichever data is published later to topic.I m not getting old data which data source has published to topic before i subscribed to topic.

for example) data source created 1 to 10 data like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
new subscriber is added to topic(using angular app if i subscribe) after emitting 5 data point.. I m getting data from 6(6,7,8,9,10) but i need data from 1 to 10

How to get all data from topic, whenever i subscribe to any new topic

Is this default way mqtt behaves?

In angular i hav heard about hot and cold observables. Is it possible to make mqtt behave as cold observable? (send all data whenever new subscriber s subscribed)

Answer (score 0):

Use `shareReplay()` operator which is for these kind of scenarios all the late subscribes will get all the values emitted. https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay

Answer (score 0):

MQTT will only queue data for clients with a persistent session (See the HiveMQ blog [post](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-7-persistent-session-queuing-messages/) for details on persistent sessions).

This means the client needs to have already been connected to the broker and subscribed to the topic in question at QOS 1 or 2.

When it reconnects it needs to use the same client id and make sure that the clean session flag is set to false.

MQTT is a pub/sub protocol, not a generic message queuing system.